# Error with datalist in edge, not show more than 10 options

Tags: datalist

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lPd7.png) I have a Datalist with more than 10 options, in chrome and Mozilla browsers it shows the options but in edge it does not show after 10 options

Comment: Having the same issue, seems to be new with Edge 91.0.864.37. Low amount of options work, when there's a lot the dropdown won't show up. Filtering by writing seems hit and miss, possibly depending on the amount of results.